# Is it okay if we assign const integer a value like this?

Tags: c++, c++17

I wanted to assign a value to a constant but as it is constant, we cant assign value to it through cin. So I came up with this idea. Is it okay if we use it like this?

```
{
    int data = 0;
    cout << "enter number of students"<<endl;
    cin>>data;
    const int number = data;
    cout << number<<endl;
    
}
```

Comment: And does it work as intended?

Comment: Yes it does. The value is assigned

Comment: So why are you asking?

Comment: I was asking if it was legal to use in professional programming.

Comment: Many programmers would just keep the data variable as non-const. I like your solution of assigning it to a combat variable and how it directly leads to Bill's abstraction as reading inside a function

Answer (score 3):

This is fine. `const` values do not need to be compile time constants. They just can't be changed after they are defined.

Similarly you could do:

```
int getNumberFromStdin() {
  int data;
  cin >> data;
  return data;
}

int main() {
  const int number = getNumberFromStdin();
}
```

Comment: Alright got it !

Answer (score 3):

Yes, because it is not an assignment; it is a declaration.

Despite looking quite similar, the two constructs are different: assignment changes something that is already declared, while the declaration sets up something new, and optionally gives it a value. The value does not need to be hard-coded, though: it can be a result of some processing, as is the case in your example.

Naturally, assignment is not allowed for constants, because they already have a value.

Comment: So you mean, it looks like assignment but actually is declaration. Quite same !